# Invitation-based access to the website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have built a page on wordpress so that visitors need to enter invitation code I email them to visit the site, or request an invitation.  My question is how can I enforce this via htaccess?
Once they enter the invitation code, they'd be able to register/login to browse around the site - which without the invitation they wouldn't be able to access any other page(s) of the site.

Comment: Can't you just use an existing plugin? https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/

Comment: This plugin will create one password to access where I need to be able to give access and revoke to different users/visitors.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with htaccess?  It would, imo, be much more straightforward and flexible to write a plugin (in php) that does this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie and I kinda like how you'd be able to protect your site via cpanel's Privet Access where you can give/assign username and password.  But that doesn't look so user friendly since visitors get hit with a popup as soon as they browse to the site.  That's why I thought that if I can place some codes in htaccess it may do the job.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for perhaps a plugin that would do the job which @Chris also suggested, I came across this plugin which can do the job as I need: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-site-protect/